# Problems with volume/mount WordPress files in Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am new to DevOps tools and experiencing Docker. I dont understand why the WordPress files and folders do not mount in the local directory. I do not know if I understand the concept and the problem correctly. I really appreciate if you could help me out there. I am using docker toolbox.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
   image: mysql:5.7
   volumes:
     - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
     MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
     MYSQL_USER: wordpress
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
  wordpress:
   depends_on:
     - db
   image: wordpress:latest
   volumes:
     - .:/var/www/html
   ports:
     - "8001:80"
   restart: always
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

What I want the project to be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlEwF.png)

And what I get after running `docker-compose up`. Basically, nothing shows up or exist.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIxyk.png)

Comment: https://headsigned.com/posts/mounting-docker-volumes-with-docker-toolbox-for-windows/ ?

Comment: One issue I am seeing is that you are not specifying `WORDPRESS_DB_NAME` in your `wordpress` service config. That might help. I have never tried to map WordPress files in from a host directory. It might work, but using a docker volume for the wp files might be cleaner. Here's an example of how I do it (you can ignore the redis/wp-cli stuff): https://github.com/collinbarrett/wp-host-on-containers/blob/master/docker-compose.collinmbarrett-com.yml

Comment: I copy-pasted your `docker-compose.yml` and it works fine for me.  It takes a little while for the files to show up (this is described in [Docker's own quickstart](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/)). Point your browser at http://localhost:8001.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. It did work normally if my project directory is in the same path with the shared folders in virtualbox, which is C:/User, but it does not work if my project is, for example, in drive A:/. I have tried many ways to mount, change the shared folder in Virtualbox (as the link suggested by Rambarun Komaljeet) but it didnt work as expected. I have also change the volume path as full path instead of relative path, `volumes: - /a/devops/docker/docker-wp:/var/www/html` I was wondering if it is because of Docker toolbox or something I have misunderstood.